# How to select indices that end with a certain number?

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
x = c(31, 56, 78, 98, 76, 88, 90)
```

and would like to select all values that end in the same number. For example, 78, 88, 98.

Comment: Curious:  why?  Would be fun to see the context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this :

```
v <- c(31,56,78,98,76,88,90)
v[v %% 10 == 8]
# [1] 78 98 88
```

Note that `v %% 10` will give you the mod of the division of `v` by 10.

Comment: Compared to the other proposed solutions this has the advantage that the indices don't have to be cast to characters first. Also, modulo is probably faster than grepl or strsplit.

Answer (score 5):

Using regular expression ,

```
x[grepl('.*8$',x)]
[1] 78 98 88
```

Comment: your current solution will match `989` as well for example. You'll have to add a `$`: `grepl(".*8$", x)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another long winded solution.

```
mmm <- c(31,56,78,98,76,88,90)
mmm[sapply(sapply(as.character(mmm), strsplit, split = ""), "[[", 2) == 8]
[1] 78 98 88
```

Comment: breaks for >2 digit numbers, isn't it?

Comment: @Arun It sure does, but it would be easy to tweak for more numbers.